# SQL insert into and DEFAULT values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an INSERT INTO statement as

```
INSERT INTO tablename (var1, var2)
SELECT othervar1, othervar2
FROM othertablename
```

The problem is that the table "tablename" have more variable than just var1 and var2. The insert statement will set Null to the other variables that are not assign values by default. The problem is that the "tablename" do not accept null values.

I could set the default value to zero for the all the relevant variables in "tablename" but I do not have access to modify the DB.

Comment: use column names in insert and pass values as 0

Comment: a table do not have variables, it has columns

Comment: Someone has made effort to ensure proper values have to be specified for some columns. (NOT NULL, combined with no default value.) Now you try to insert dummy values into these columns. Seems like a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Yes I see your Point. I forgot to mention that the table have alot of COLUMN names and I thought one could use a more efficiant way than  manually set all the columns to zero. Also the reason why proper value are not inserted is that the correct data is not in place yet

Comment: have you tried firing an alter table query?

Answer (score 0):

Add the columns and the values to `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements

```
INSERT INTO tablename (var1, var2, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT othervar1, othervar2, 'default','default','default'
FROM othertablename
```

BTW: a table do not have variables, it has columns

Answer (score 0):

IF you do not have access or can't update table columns default value,

so try to change the query and insert desire values...

like that:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (var1, var2, field3, field4)
SELECT othervar1, othervar2, 0, 0
FROM othertablename
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set default value for each field as per below picture i have shared.
you have to give default  value in that textbox.

[image: set field default value]